# Creating a form inside a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, gridview

I currently have a gridview with data that is binded from the database.  This data is suppose to be editable and deleteable.

Is it possible to create a form within the grid view?

ie when you click on an item in the gridview, everything below or above moves down/up to create some room for a new editing pane with two dropdownlist and a few icons for delete/update.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a ListView, not a GridView.

Comment: How is the transition from ListView to GridView?

Comment: ListView does not have all that GUI garbage that you do not want. You'll have to implement all that yourself - which is what you say you want. Start reading!

Answer (score 0):

The gridview itself has some features to edit, add, delete etc. Check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx. It has kind of a learning curve though, so you must read to be able to do cool stuff with the Gridview.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is not exactly what I am looking for.  I have played with it before and it feels to clunky.  I want to get rid of the delete, edit, select buttons and make it feel more dynamic.

Comment: Then  as TheGeekYouNeed suggested you should probably use a GridView ListView combination.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that sort of functionality with   **Telerik's**  grid control[Telerik ASP.NET Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/usercontroleditform/defaultcs.aspx).
You can open a modal popup on eidt/insert if your form fields are many otherwise gridview's inbuilt editing would do just fine.

[Add edit update gridview records using modal popup](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Edit-Update-Records-in-GridView-using-Modal-Popup-in-ASP.Net.aspx)